# Automatically generate material course based on the corresponding beamer slideshow

Tags: beamer, formatting

I have a teaching course in the form of a pretty long beamer slideshow (like more than 300 slides).

Now I would like to create a course material in such a way that, on each page, the reader finds one slide from the slideshow inserted in the page, with some textual explanation placed right next to it, for instance:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
+  +----------------------+   slide i                         +
+  +      This is         +   Blabla bla bla bla bla bla  bla +
+  +  slide #i from the   +   bla blabla bla blabla   bla bla +
+  +      original        +   blabla bla bla blabla bla   bla +
+  +  beamer slideshow    +   blabla bla  bla bla bla bla bla +
+  +  (PDF inserted e.g   +   blabla bla blablabla blabla bla +
+  +  w/ includegraphics) +   blabla bla bla blabla bla   bla +
+  +----------------------+   blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla  +
+                             blabla bla bla  blabla bla bla  +
+  Blabla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla bla bla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+  bla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla +
+-------------------------------------------------------------+

(sorry but this is not code of course!)
```

An example of that kind of layout can be seen here (follow the Amazon "Look inside" link and go for instance to page viii):
[https://www.amazon.com/Design-Essentials-Integrated-Circuits-Systems/dp/0387717129](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387717129)
(it's the book "Low power essentials" by Jan Rabaey).

If I automatically excerpt each slide of the original beamer slideshow
in one separate PDF file (without having to compile 300 times, one for each slide while commenting all the others and not to mention the possible cross-reference errors...) I could then generate the material course using another LaTeX file, automatically based on the slideshow. All I'd have to do would be to create the text associated to each slide.

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: You can label slides and import them, see 21.2.3 Including Slides from the Presentation Version in the Article Version in the beamer documentation. And you can anyway include an arbitrary  page from a pdf with \includegraphics[page=X]{..}.

Comment: I'd put it in one source file, I think. At least, no separate the slides from the text. Then tell Beamer to ignore non-frame text for slides and use a different wrapper with `beamerarticle` for the combined version.

Comment: You can delete your own answer if you have already found a solution with `pdftk` tool.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by some method undisclosed by the OP